# Default IDLE (Python 2.7) font

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-idle

I accidently changed my default font in IDLE Python.. and don't remember the original font name... so can't change back to original font.

Please tell the default font name used in IDLE..

To check,use these steps...

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3YDe.png)

Enter the Options menu, and select Configure IDLE button

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNKuC.png)

View the font currently selected

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Comic Sans MS Mono

Comment: go to your `user/.idlec` folder and delete the `config-main.cfg` file to revert to original settings (requires restarting IDLE) on my machine the default is `Monaco` and there are now two other people saying differently so deleting the user settings is the only way to get it back exactly to what **you** had before.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist my professor actually used Comic Sans because he thought it was funny :|

Comment: Including the ``python-idle`` tag would make this question even more relevant...

Answer (score 15):

The default font for IDLE is **Courier New**

Comment: It's not really crazily off topic. IDLE definitely falls under ["tools used primarily for programming"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If there were some obvious way in which restoring the default font would contribute to one's ability to effectively program, it'd be clearly on topic, but IDLE's default font is awful for code.

Answer (score 3):

When ever you change a setting in IDLE it stores the setting in the folder:

```
/path/to/user/.idlerc
```

normally it is hidden but you can access it by typing the path directly in a file browser or showing hidden folders, once you can access it delete (or rename) the file `config-main.cfg` to revert to the default settings.

Alternatively you can see the exact setting specified by default by taking a look in the `idlelib` directory of the standard library, the configuration file should be located:

```
stdlib_folder/idlelib/config-main.def
```

you can get the folder's exact location by showing the `__file__` inside the python shell:

```
>>> import idlelib
>>> idlelib.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/__init__.pyc'
```

On my machine the relevent line in `config-main.def` is:

```
font= TkFixedFont
```

Which I believe means "what ever Tk defines as default fixed font for this OS" so there really isn't any default font for all instances of IDLE.

Comment: The use of TkFixedFont was added in the Fall 2015 releases (2.7.11, 3.4.4, 3.5.1).  Before, the default was Courier or Courier New (I forget) for everyone.  I cannot tell from the question which specific version was at issue.

Comment: hence my answer being "this is how you reset the settings" and not "here is the default" because I figured the default was dependant on information I did not have.